# Cargar tabla JSP con Ajax en success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring

Buenas tardes con todos como puedo hacer que mi **"tabla JSP"** pueda recargar la lista de elementos que tiene en mi `Base de datos` con `ajax`, estoy usando `Spring` y `JSTL`.
**Este es mi código "JSP - Bienvenido" para cargar los datos de mi BD**

```
<tbody id="tbl_contenido">
    <c:forEach items="${datos}" var="dato">
    <tr>
        <td class="id"><c:out value="${dato.codigo_Pers}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${dato.nombre_Pers}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${dato.apellido_Pat_Pers}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${dato.apellido_Mat_Pers}" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Modificar js" class="btnModificar">
            <input type="button" value="Eliminar js" class="btnEliminar">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

**Con este código "JSP" simple inserto un registro. (Este código se encuentra en la misma página pero con un tabla diferente).**

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Codigo</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtNombre_Pers"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtApellido_Pat_Pers"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtApellido_Mat_Pers"></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="btnRegistrar" value="Registrar persona"></td>
</tr>
```

**Este es mi archivo "JQuery", y aquí es donde me quedo.**

```
$('#btnRegistrar').click(function () {
    var nombre = $('#txtNombre_Pers').val();
    var apellidoPat = $('#txtApellido_Pat_Pers').val();
    var apellidoMat = $('#txtApellido_Mat_Pers').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../controladorPersona/procesarPersona',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            txtNombre:nombre,
            txtApellidoPat:apellidoPat,
            txtApellidoMat:apellidoMat
        },
        success: function (resultado) {
            alert("Se insertó correctamente.");
        }
    });
});
```

Bueno todo el código funciona y me inserta un registro correctamente incluso con el mensaje pero el único inconveniente que tengo es que en este código no se como hacer en `success: function (resultado){...}` para poder actualizar mi tabla de mi `JSP` sin recargar la página.
**Este es mi Controlador donde recibo datos**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/procesarPersona")
public ModelAndView procesarPersona(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(); 
    String nombre = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
    String apellidoPat = request.getParameter("txtApellidoPat");
    String apellidoMat = request.getParameter("txtApellidoMat");
    Persona pers = new Persona(nombre, apellidoPat, apellidoMat);
    boolean resp = Persona_Dao.registrarPersona(pers);
    if(resp == true){
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/controladorVista/Bienvenido.htm"); 
    }else{
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/controladorVista/index.htm"); 
    }
    return mv;
}
```

**Este controlador muestra la vista JSP**, el cual su contenido ya está en la parte superior de esta pregunta.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Bienvenido.htm")
public ModelAndView Bienvenido() throws SQLException{
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    List<Persona> datos = Persona_Dao.listarPersonas();
    mv.addObject("datos", datos);
    mv.setViewName("Bienvenido");
    return mv; 
}
```

**Un favor me podrían ayudar con el código "JQuery" que me falta, cualquier respuesta que me ayude a solucionar sería util.**

Comment: Tu controlador debería retornar en formato de texto plano o json los datos que has guardado en la db, incluyendo el código que se le generó. sobretodo el código.

Comment: Hola @Christian Carrillo mi `controlador` donde registro retorna un `ModelAndView` que redirige a otro `controlador` donde ese retorna una **"vista o página JSP"** para mostrar la tabla el cual su estructura está escrito en la primera parte de esta pregunta. Entonces en que `controlador` debo retornar `json` en donde registro o en donde muestro los datos de mi tabla, o en los dos, de todos modos gracias por tomarte la molestia de responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar esta lógica:

```js
// target al tbody de la table
const $tblContenido = $('#tbl_contenido')
// target al btn Registrar
const $btnRegistrar = $('#btnRegistrar')
// target a los inputs
const $nombre = $('#txtNombre_Pers')
const $apellidoPat = $('#txtApellido_Pat_Pers')
const $apellidoMat = $('#txtApellido_Mat_Pers')

function simularRequestAlControlador(data) {
  // en data estaría la respuesta del servidor en este caso está como un
  // objeto de JS, que podría ser equivalente al json que retornaría el server
  data.codigo = 3 // hardcodeando el código que retornaría el servidor 
  
  // esta variable guarda el template de la fila que ingresarías a tu table
  // usando (template string) para interpolar las variables de un modo más legible
  const row = `
   <tr>
      <td class="id">${data.codigo}</td>
      <td>${data.nombre}</td>
      <td>${data.apellido_Pat}</td>
      <td>${data.apellido_Mat}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Modificar js" class="btnModificar">
        <input type="button" value="Eliminar js" class="btnEliminar">
      </td>
    </tr>
    `
  
  // inserta la fila dentro de la table
  $tblContenido.append(row)        
}

// listener al button registrar que llamará a la función simularRequestAlControlador
// luego de 3seg simulando el tiempo que demoraría en responder el servidor
$btnRegistrar.on('click', function() {
  const data = {
    nombre: $nombre.val(),
    apellido_Pat: $apellidoPat.val(),
    apellido_Mat: $apellidoMat.val()   
  }
  setTimeout(function() { 
    simularRequestAlControlador(data) 
  }, 3000);
})
```

```css
.registro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Registrar<h4>
<div class="registro">
  Nombre<input type="text" id="txtNombre_Pers">
  Apellido_Pat<input type="text" id="txtApellido_Pat_Pers">
  Apellido_Mat<input type="text" id="txtApellido_Mat_Pers">
    <input type="button" id="btnRegistrar" value="Registrar persona">
</div>

<h4>Personas<h4>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>codigo</th>
      <th>nombre</th>
      <th>apellido_Pat</th>
      <th>apellido_Mat</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl_contenido">
    <tr>
      <td class="id">1</td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Modificar js" class="btnModificar">
        <input type="button" value="Eliminar js" class="btnEliminar">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">2</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Modificar js" class="btnModificar">
        <input type="button" value="Eliminar js" class="btnEliminar">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias @Christian Carrillo por el aporte que me brindas, pero si lo hago con `json` ¿el procedimiento sería el mismo? o varía mucho.

Comment: si el controlador o endpoint responde con un json si, si respondes en texto plano/string tendrías que parsearlo.